# Regex for doubling single quotes in string

Tags: sql, regex

I would like a regex that would make this:

```
VALUES('Hit 'n Run')
```

into

```
VALUES('Hit ''n Run')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Using regex to avoid properly escaping dynamic SQL? bad idea

Comment: So answer and tell him where to find a routine for this job?

Comment: How would I know which apostrophe is the terminating apostrophe? Can I count on (' and ') being the start and end patterns? (knowing SQL I usually can't in general but this is your code)

Comment: Why would you need a regex to do this? A simple replace would do the job.

Comment: @bmargulies: This is the wrong job to do in the first place. The regexp in question is simple `s/'/''/g` but cannot be run at this point in the code. It should be run on the input string before the query string was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not really possible. If you have `VALUES('Hit 'n Run')`, you already have an invalid mixture of delimiting apostrophes and literal apostrophes. String processing is like mixing sugar and salt: once you've mixed contexts without proper escaping there is no way of pulling them back apart.

If you are trying to rescue broken data, you could try something like `(?<!\()'(?!\))` to match apostrophes that don't have a bracket next to them. It's a weak and easily fooled tactic but for simple data it might work.

If you are putting together dynamic SQL queries you must escape the `'` *before* you put it into the query string, either using a simple string replace `'` with `''` if you're sure that's the only escape your DBMS requires, or — much better — using a dedicated SQL-string-literal-escaping function appropriate to your DBMS. Quite what that function would be depends on what platform (language, DBMS) you're talking about.

Comment: I figured, but i thought i would check first. I have a lot of sql string that aren't escaped and all are sent to a "execute" method. So i figured i could save time by just escaping the parameter. Well, nothing to do then.

Comment: Or *a lot more* to do depending on how you look at it. I'm not sure what language/framework you're using but refactoring that code to use parameterized queries may be worth the effort.

Comment: The methods that builds the query takes an object as a parameter and extracts data from that. By nothing to do then, i actually meant nothing to do but to escape every single method.

Comment: +1 for parameterised queries. If available in your environment, they're likely to be more pleasant to use than many calls to string escape.

Answer (score 2):

Any pattern that could be expressed in RegEx could then be exploited to create the very SQL injection issues you're trying to avoid.

Example nasty input:

```
VALUES(');DELETE * FROM customer;SELECT '
```

Comment: Actually, i'm not avoiding that. It is a private application for home use. So the only one one would sabotage by  doing that it oneself.

Comment: *The Bicentennial Man* was a good movie, but you can use 'I' and 'me' online, really. :)